# select a row which has s specific word or accept all records if it's not set

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In `PHP` side I have to filter my query due to the parameters received from `$_POST`. So if the parameters are set, query has to filter results related to params, if not, query should omit the condition. What I want to do is just write one query to switch between 2 different condition

```
$name = $_POST['name']!="" ? $_POST['name'] :"" ;
$family = $_POST['family']!="" ? $_POST['family'] :"" ;
$country = $_POST['country']!="" ? $_POST['country'] :"" ;
$where[1] = $name!="" ? 'name LIKE "%%s%%"' :TRUE ;
$where[2] = $family !="" ? 'family LIKE "%%s%%"' :TRUE ;
$where[3] = $country !="" ? 'country LIKE "%%s%%"' :TRUE ;
$sql = "SELECT *
            FROM {$tbl}
            WHERE {$where[1]} AND {$where[2]} AND {$where[3]} AND 
            soft_delete IS NULL OR soft_delete < 1
       ";
$query = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $name, $family, $country);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

What I want is if one of those parameters isn't set, query has not filter the query. for example, if just `$name` is set, query filter records according to name field and the other conditions must be true

Comment: You could create a set of prepared statements, and choose the appropriate one depending on which query parameters are defined on the incoming request.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , yeah, this is the primitive solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM {$tbl}
        WHERE ";

if (!$where[1] && !$where[2] && !$where[3]) {
    $sql .= "{$where[1]} AND {$where[2]} AND {$where[3]} AND";
}

$sql .= " soft_delete IS NULL OR soft_delete < 1";
```

Comment: my problem is when I send parameters into `wpdb->prepare()` it returns `$results` with no records